# Passing variable javascript to php in one js function

Tags: php, yii

i have function like this below, how to send value of variable firstColVal in js to variable $no_loan in php , its there in one function js ? i have try on try but i still can't get the value ?

pls help me and thanks much before

```
function addPembayaran()
{
$("#tbangsuran-grid table tbody tr").click(function()
       {
            $this=$(this);
            var firstColVal= $this.find('td:first-child').text();
            var secondColVal= $this.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            var lastColVal= $this.find('td:last-child').text();


    <?php 
         $no_loan =$_POST['firstColVal'];
            echo CHtml::ajax(array(
            'url'=>array('Tbpembayaran/create'),
           'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize()",
            //'data'=> array('noloan'=>'20'),
            // data: {ad_id:"hello"},
            'type'=>'post',
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'success'=>"function(data)
            {
                if (data.status == 'failure')
                {
                    $('#dialogPembayaran div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                          // Here is the trick: on submit-> once again this function!
                    $('#dialogPembayaran div.divForForm form').submit(addPembayaran);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#dialogPembayaran div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                    setTimeout(\"$('#dialogPembayaran').dialog('close') \",3000);
                }

            } ",
            ))


            ?>;
   // return false; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods to do this:

1. Save that variable on Session in javascript adn get it from php
2. use [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to where you want to `$no_loan` which must be a global variable there

   $.post( "Tbpembayaran/save_no_loan/"+$('input[name="firstColVal"]').val(), function( ) {
       });

Also you have to write a function to set that `$no_loan` with

```
save_no_loan($fromjs)
{
$this->no_loan=$fromjs;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have try method one to use session use java script like this sessionStorage.setItem("noloan", "firstColVal"); but i can't get the session. could you give, how to way create session using js ?

Answer (score 0):

CHtml will do a request to the given url,

the parameters being sent are in:

```
'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize()",
```

and these are passed to here:

```
'url'=>array('Tbpembayaran/create'),
```

so if you want to pass more variables, you can add more to `data`:

```
'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize() + '&anotherVariable=' $(this).find('td:first-child').text()", // I think this should do the trick
```

Comment: i get error "Object of class TbangsuranController could not be converted to string" , tks

Comment: I meant `$(this).find('td:first-child').text()` or however you need to select your value

Comment: if i fill '&anotherVariable=100, the controller in url can get the value but if i use $(this).find('td:first-child').text() will be error

Comment: dear I don't know what are you trying to assign to `anotherVariable` or what is your html markup! just check first in fireBug or something  that if `$(this).find('td:first-child').text()` will select your desired value or not. if not try another selector,right?

Answer (score 0):

One:

```
'data' => "js:{no_loan:$no_loan}"
```

or:

```
'url' => array('Tbpembayaran/create','no_loan'=>$no_loan)
```